# MS access: How to delete the selected item from Combobox when button pressed?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

***Case:*** I have a CommandButton and an unbound ComboBox in a form (RowSourceType: list of values - populated from another form using VBA).

***Goal:*** When a user clicks on the CommandButton, the selected item in the ComboBox to be deleted from this ComboBox.

***Attempts:*** I used in the Click event of the CommandButton, the RemoveItem method of the ComboBox, which needs the index of the item-to-delete.
To get the index of the selected item, I tried to use the Selected property of the ComboBox, looping through all the ComboBox items, but the Selected property keeps returning 0 regrdless of the selection.

```
Private Sub bDelete_Click()
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Me.cAnswered.ListCount - 1
        If Me.cAnswered.Selected(i) = True Then
            'MsgBox i
            'Stop
            Me.cAnswered.RemoveItem i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Me.bDelete.Visible = (Me.cAnswered.ListCount > 0)
End Sub
```

Can you please tell me how can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
Private Sub bDelete_Click()
 Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Me.cAnswered.ListCount - 1
        If Me.cAnswered.ItemData(i) = cAnswered.Value Then
            Me.cAnswered.RemoveItem i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    cAnswered = Null
End Sub
```

Comment: Τested, everything OK! Thank you very much for dealing with this.